# Regex not working as expected with C++ regex_match

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm studying regular expressions in c++11 and this regex search is returning false.  Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here? .  I know that `.*` stands for any number of characters except newlines.

So i was expecting regex_match() to return true and the output to be "found".
However the output is coming out to be "not found".

```
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool found = regex_match("<html>",regex("h.*l"));// works for "<.*>"
    cout<<(found?"found":"not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of compiler do you use? Some versions of gcc support c++11 but do not fully support regex

Comment: the question has been answered regex_match does not work for subsequences

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use a `regex_search` rather than `regex_match`:

```
bool found = regex_search("<html>",regex("h.*l"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Au9XdV)

In plain words, `regex_search` will search for a substring at *any* position in the given string. `regex_match` will only return true if the *entire* input string is matched (same behavior as `matches` in Java).

The [regex_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) documentation says:

> Returns whether the target sequence matches the regular expression `rgx`.
>   The entire target sequence must match the regular expression for this function >to return true (i.e., without any additional characters before or after the >match). For a function that returns true when the match is only part of the >sequence, see `regex_search`.

The [regex_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) is different:

> Returns whether some sub-sequence in the target sequence (the subject) matches the regular expression `rgx` (the pattern).